# Is the use of the word "status quo" correct in the provided sentence?

Tags: word-choice

The sentence is **Plunging  power sector in an unsustainable status quo, authorities admitted that the power plants weren’t being run optimally.**

**Reasons for confusion**

Status quo means the current state of affairs. However attaching the word unsustainable seems awkward since the sentence now reads ...unsustainable current state of affairs...

Comment: What's awkward about it?  (unsustainable) (current) (state of affairs) - unsustainable and current are adjectives, state of affairs is a noun phrase.  The current state of affairs is unsustainable = it won't be this way for long.

Comment: Well I tried to say it out loud and it seemed awkward so I though my choice of words must be wrong.

Comment: It's long and has lots of syllables, but it's a relatively complicated idea.

Comment: Is that the complete sentence? I don't see how 'plunging ...' can apply to 'authorities'. The register is wrong for a 'With a' deletion.

Comment: The sentence is meaningless as it stands. Please provide a more complete context or sentence.

Comment: *Plunging* applies to *authorities,* @EdwinAshworth, in that *authorities* is the subject of the front-shifted participial phrase: the authorities plunged the sector into crisis by their admission. But *status quo* is definitely the wrong term for the crisis into which the sector is being plunged. The admission creates the crisis, which did not exist before, and the status quo by definition *did* exist before.

Comment: Did you write the sentence or did you find it somewhere? If the latter, please cite the source and provide a link to it.

Comment: I wrote the sentence

Comment: @BrianDonovan so the word "status quo" is wrong here? Can you then please provide a different word which can work as an alternative?

Comment: @Brian Donovan If you're guessing correctly that the intro should read 'Plunging the power sector into an unsustainable status quo', then of course you're correct. But ELU isn't about guesswork.

Answer (score 2):

*Plunging power sector in an unsustainable status quo, authorities admitted that the power plants weren’t being run optimally.*

Maybe the first part means that the the power sector plunged, or was plunged, into an unsustainable state, or status.

Maybe it means that the authorities plunged the power sector into some sorry state, and they kept bringing it down, and so you say that the downward trend was a stable feature of the power sector, and thus the downward trend was the status quo.

Maybe you're just giving a description of the scene.  The plunging might just be a backdrop.

We are also told that authorities admitted that the power plants weren’t being run optimally.  But I didn't understand the connection between this and the plunging.

Aim for being clear enough for even not very smart people like me to understand your idea.

Anyway, to answer your question.

I like the wiktionary definition the best:

> The state of things; the way things are, as opposed to the way they could be; the existing state of affairs.

So, in general, you can say that something is unsustainable, and you can talk about status quo (the current state of affairs).  For example, you could say

> Energy use in Country XX has held steady for the last 3 years.  This level of usage is unsustainable.  To remain in *status quo* would result in a complete depletion of the country's energy reserves in YY years.

However, *status quo* is not dynamic, it is static.  The presence of the word "plunging" suggests the system is in rapid flux.  So the way you used "status quo" makes me queasy, so even though I don't understand your sentence, my opinion is, don't use *status quo* in this way.

Comment: Since the authorities aren't running the power plants optimally, the power generation is very low. As a result, the power sector is very dire condition. (In response to your " I don't understand the connection between power plants run optimally and plunging of power sector")

Comment: @FaiqRaees - Great explanation.  Did you see, you wrote simple sentences, and even I understood them!  That's the style to aim for.  My partner is always trying to get me to simplify my sentence structure and says, "Think Hemingway!"

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback. However, by reading articles, I have developed a sense of feeling that sentences which have a complex nature are considered more professional (a key element when writing university essays).

Comment: @FaiqRaees - Well, there are two rules of thumb that can help all technical writers, including native English speakers: (1) Make sure it's easily understandable, and (2) Don't write complex sentences just for the sake of making it look sophisticated.  I recommend a two-step process.  First draft: annoyingly short sentences.  Once all the ideas are clearly expressed, such that the less smart sector of your readership can easily grasp your ideas, then in the second draft you may start combining clauses into more graceful writing.  Then show the whole draft to someone, and ask him to ...

Comment: highlight any parts that are hard to understand.  For those parts, it can be helpful to go back to the simple sentences of the first draft. // When you're posing questions on ELU, it could be helpful to share both the complex sentence you're checking, *and* the Hemingway version.